# call to undefined method lluminate\Database\Query\Builder::username(), when adding new tuple to table

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to create an add() method to my UserRepository in **Laravel4**. The repository is found in the roBlog namespace. When i call `$user->username` method passing the username member of the credentials array, the application throws the error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::username()`.

the table that User represents has a username attribute.

and i have imported the Builder class from Illuminate.

does anyone know why i am getting this error?

```
namespace roBlog\repositories; 
use roBlog\User;          
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

class DbUserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface { 

public function all()
{ 
    return User::all()->toArray();
}
public function add($credentials)
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->username($credentials['username']);
    $user->emai($credentials['email']);
    $user->password(Hash::make($credentials['username']));
    $user->save();
}
public function remove($user){
    return $user->delete();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must:

```
public function add($credentials)
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->username = $credentials['username'];
    $user->email = $credentials['email'];
    $user->password = Hash::make($credentials['password']);
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: oh dear, well thats embarrasing. I think its time to go to bed. thanks muchos.